# JavaScript function expression assigned to a variable (pass by reference or value?)

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have a doubt about the following codes. I thought that data-type primitives assigned to a variable in JS were passed by value, while objects were passed by reference. If functions are objects in JS, I thought they should be passed by reference, but the following two codes behave as passed by value:

**CODE 1**

```
var x = function hello(){ console.log("hello")};

console.log(x);

var y = x;

console.log(y);

x = function bye(){console.log("bye")};

console.log(x);

console.log(y);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[Function: hello]
[Function: hello]
[Function: bye]
[Function: hello]
```

**CODE 2**

In this case I assigned a method to a global variable and the behavior is the same:

```
var x = {name:"Max",
        action: function one(){console.log("one")}
}

var y = x.action;

console.log(y);

x.action = function two(){console.log("two")};

console.log(x.action);

console.log(y);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[Function: one]
[Function: two]
[Function: one]
```

I truly appreciate any insight and explanation on this.

Comment: You are reassigning variables. Not modifying them by-reference.

Comment: JS does not have pass by reference. Always pass by value, but that value can be a reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Niet. In code 1, how could I modify the function "hello" assigned to variable x by reference, instead of reassigning it?

Answer (score 2):

From that regard, JavaScript is pass-by-value.

Assigning variable X to variable Y will place the value of X in Y, even if the value of X is a reference to an object.

You can see the "by reference" nature that you're looking for when you modify a deeper property in an object:

```
var x = { foo: () => "bar"; }
var y = x;

x.foo = () => "baz";

y.foo(); // "baz", and not "bar".
```

If I were to set `x` to `{ foo: () => "baz" }`, `y.foo()` would still result in `"bar"`, because I didn't modify the original object, I replaced it with another.

---

To clarify, JavaScript does *not* have `var x = &y;` or something similar like in PHP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Madara. I'm aware of the example you posted. Now, how could I modify in code 1, the function hello, by reference?

Answer (score 0):

In this code `y` won't be reference of `x` later, `x` is re-assigned with a new function. If you modify a property in `x`, `y` will still be a reference of `x` then.

The same happens with every object in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply assigning functions to variables, there's nothing tricky in this code and it's working as it should, feel free to ask something more.

Answer (score 0):

Pass by reference/value doesn't matter here as there is no passing involved.

The values that these variable contain is a reference to a function. I think what you're expecting is that `y` and `x` are linked somehow after the assignment but the assignment only changes what function `y` refers to with no further association with `x`.

First `x` holds a reference to `hello`, then `y` is set to hold a reference to `hello`, then `x` is set to contain a reference to `bye`. So at the end, `x` contains a reference to `bye`, and `y` contains a reference to hello.

This is basically the same as:

```
var x = "hello";
var y = x;
x = "bye";

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```